# Vectorising a mutlitple condition dataframe merge

Tags: r, merge, vectorization

I am trying to merge two data frames. The original data frame is much larger than the data frame that is going to be merged with however there is only 1 possible match for each row. The row is found by matching the type (a factor) and the level. The level is an integer that will be put into one of several buckets (the example only has two)

My current method works but uses sapply and is slow for large numbers of rows. How can I vectorise this operation?

```
set.seed(123)
sample <- 100
data <- data.frame(type= sample(LETTERS[1:4], sample, replace=TRUE), level =round(runif(sample, 1,sample)), value = round(runif(sample, 200,1000)))

data2 <- data.frame(type= rep(LETTERS[1:4],2), lower= c(rep(1,4), rep(51,4)), upper = c(rep(50,4), rep(sample,4)), cost1 = runif(8, 0,1), cost2 = runif(8, 0,1),cost3 = runif(8, 0,1))
data2[,4:6] <- data2[,4:6]/rowSums(data2[,4:6]) #turns the variables in to percentages, not necessary on real data

x <- unlist(sapply(1:sample, function(n) which(ll <-data$type[n]==data2$type & data$level[n] >= data2$lower & data$level[n] <= data2$upper)))

data3 <- cbind(data, percentage= data2[x, -c(1:3)])
```

Comment: Sure changed, it doesn't effect the question.

Comment: Have you tried `lapply` instead of `sapply` since you are unlisting anyway?  It's generally faster and at times can be a lot faster

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tested it using microbenchmark but it didn't make much of a difference, however I will bear it in mind when doing similar operations in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the matching problem you've set up, the following code seems to speed things up a bit by dividing data by type and then using cut to find the proper bucket.  I think it will accommodate larger numbers of pairs of lower and upper values but haven't checked carefully.

```
library(plyr) 
percents <- function(value, cost) {
   cost <- cost[cost[,1]== value[1,1],]
   cost <- cost[order(cost[,2]),]
   ints <- cut(value[,2], breaks=c(t(cost[,2:3])), labels=FALSE, include.lowest=TRUE )
   cbind(value,percentage=cost[ceiling(ints/2),-(1:3)])
}
data4 <- rbind.fill(mapply(percents, value=split(data, data$type), cost=list(data2), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)  )
```

Setting

```
sample <- 10000
```

gives the following execution time comparisons

```
microbenchmark({x <- unlist(sapply(1:sample, function(n) which(ll <-data$type[n]==data2$type & data$level[n] >= data2$lower & data$level[n] <= data2$upper)));
             data3 <- cbind(data, percentage= data2[x, -c(1:3)])} ,
             data4 <- rbind.fill(mapply(percents, value=split(data, data$type), cost=list(data2), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)  ),
            times=10)

Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            expr
{     x <- unlist(sapply(1:sample, function(n) which(ll <- data$type[n] ==          data2$type & data$level[n] >= data2$lower & data$level[n] <=          data2$upper)))     data3 <- cbind(data, percentage = data2[x, -c(1:3)]) }
                                                                                                                data4 <- rbind.fill(mapply(percents, value = split(data, data$type),      cost = list(data2), SIMPLIFY = FALSE))

       min         lq       mean     median        uq        max neval
1198.18269 1214.10560 1225.85117 1226.79838 1234.2671 1258.63122    10
  20.81022   20.93255   21.50001   21.24237   22.1305   22.65291    10
```

> 

where the first numbers are for the code shown in your question and the second times are for the code in my post.  For this case, the new code seems almost 60 times faster.

### Edit

To use rbind_all and avoid mapply, use the following:

```
microbenchmark({x <- unlist(sapply(1:sample, function(n) which(ll <-data$type[n]==data2$type & data$level[n] >= data2$lower & data$level[n] <= data2$upper)));
            data3 <- cbind(data, percentage= data2[x, -c(1:3)])} ,
           data4 <- rbind_all(lapply(split(data, data$type), percents, cost=data2  )),
           times=10)
```

which gives slightly improved execution times

```
       min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
1271.57023 1289.17614 1297.68572 1301.84540 1308.31476 1313.56822    10
  18.33819   18.57373   23.28578   19.53742   19.95132   58.96143    10
```

### Edit 2

Modification to use the data2$lower values only for setting intervals

```
percents <- function(value, cost) {
  cost <- cost[cost[,"type"] == value[1,"type"],]
  cost <- cost[order(cost[,"lower"]),]
  ints <- cut(value[,"value"], breaks= c(cost[,"lower"], max(cost[,"upper"])), labels=FALSE, right=FALSE, include.highest=TRUE )
  cbind(value,percentage=cost[ints,-(1:3)])
}
```

to use with

```
data4 <- rbind_all(lapply(split(data, data$type), percents, cost=data2  ))
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I switched rbind.fill for rbind_all from the dplyr package which was slightly faster. I tried to convert my function to a mapply format but kept getting an "operator is invalid for atomic vectors" invalid for atomic vectors error, is there a quick answer to this or shoudl I start a new question?

Comment: I've updated the code to use rbind_all.  Also I was wondering about the use of lower and upper bounds for assigning costs.  Code could be simplified if you could use just the lower bounds to define intervals.

Comment: You're right the upper bounds aren't necessary, it would be pretty awesome if you could show me how the code could be simplified.